# How do I solve "Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException Setting unknown property: craft\fields\Assets::branchLimit"

Tags: craftcms

```
yii\base\UnknownPropertyException: Setting unknown property: craft\fields\Assets::branchLimit in /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php:209
```

Stack trace:
#0 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(558): yii\base\Component->__set('branchLimit', NULL)
#1 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php(107): yii\BaseYii::configure(Object(craft\fields\Assets), Array)
#2 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/base/Model.php(78): yii\base\BaseObject->__construct(Array)
#3 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/fields/BaseRelationField.php(252): craft\base\Model->__construct(Array)
#4 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/fields/Assets.php(220): craft\fields\BaseRelationField->__construct(Array)
#5 [internal function]: craft\fields\Assets->__construct(Array)
#6 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(419): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#7 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(170): yii\di\Container->build('craft\fields\As...', Array, Array)
#8 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(365): yii\di\Container->get('craft\fields\As...', Array, Array)
#9 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/Craft.php(53): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array, Array)
#10 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/helpers/Component.php(121): Craft::createObject(Array)
#11 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Fields.php(593): craft\helpers\Component::createComponent(Array, 'craft\base\Fiel...')
#12 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Fields.php(618): craft\services\Fields->createField(Array)
#13 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Fields.php(647): craft\services\Fields->_fields(NULL)
#14 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/elements/db/ElementQuery.php(1908): craft\services\Fields->getAllFields()
#15 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/elements/db/ElementQuery.php(1277): craft\elements\db\ElementQuery->customFields()
#16 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/QueryBuilder.php(227): craft\elements\db\ElementQuery->prepare(Object(craft\db\mysql\QueryBuilder))
#17 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Query.php(157): yii\db\QueryBuilder->build(Object(craft\elements\db\UserQuery))
#18 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Query.php(287): yii\db\Query->createCommand(Object(craft\db\Connection))
#19 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/db/Query.php(180): yii\db\Query->one(NULL)
#20 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/elements/db/ElementQuery.php(1440): craft\db\Query->one(NULL)
#21 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/elements/User.php(535): craft\elements\db\ElementQuery->one()
#22 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/User.php(697): craft\elements\User::findIdentity(1)
#23 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/User.php(500): yii\web\User->renewAuthStatus()
#24 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/User.php(198): craft\web\User->renewAuthStatus()
#25 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(423): yii\web\User->getIdentity()
#26 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(107): craft\web\Application->debugBootstrap()
#27 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php(109): craft\web\Application->init()
#28 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(204): yii\base\BaseObject->__construct(Array)
#29 [internal function]: yii\base\Application->__construct(Array)
#30 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(419): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#31 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(170): yii\di\Container->build('craft\web\Appli...', Array, Array)
#32 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(365): yii\di\Container->get('craft\web\Appli...', Array, Array)
#33 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/Craft.php(53): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array, Array)
#34 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/bootstrap.php(239): Craft::createObject(Array)
#35 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/web.php(40): require('/Users/blessing...')
#36 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/web/index.php(21): require('/Users/blessing...')
#37 {main}